# I want to make numbers that is differnet one another but repeated numbers appeat

Tags: c++

I want to make Lotto numbers so i need 7 different numbers.
I use shuffle algorithm using index swap.
But repeated numbers appear.
help me.
below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    //로또만들기
    // 45개 수를 배열해놓고 6개랑 추가 숫자 1개를 가져다가 써야한다.
    // 1~45까지의 '겹치지 않는' 수를 이용하기위해서는 조합의 개념으로 임의로 배열되어
    // 잇는 상황`enter code here`에서 6개를 뽑는게 좋다. 일단45개를 배열해놓고
    //인덱스를 swap하면 이걸 반복하면 임의로 섞이면서 shuffle이 이루어진`enter code
    // here`다.
    int iLotto[45] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 45; ++i) {
        iLotto[i] = i + 1;
    }

    //타임에 시드값을 주자
    srand(unsigned int(time(0)));

    //마음대로 뽑을 인덱스가 필요하다
    int iTemp, iIndex1, iIndex2;

    //이제 iLotto의 값을 섞어보자
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        iIndex1 = rand() % 45;
        iIndex2 = rand() % 45;

        iTemp = iIndex1;
        iLotto[iTemp] = iLotto[iIndex1];
        iLotto[iIndex1] = iLotto[iIndex2];
        iLotto[iIndex2] = iLotto[iTemp];
    }

    //이제 6개 숫자와 추가숫자 1개를 뽑아보자
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        cout << iLotto[i] << "\t";
    }

    cout << "추가숫자:\t" << iLotto[7];
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure `iIndex1` & `iIndex2` are not equal before including them in the array.

Comment: I realized that iTemp should be out of index. Thankyou for your comment.

Comment: Please translate comments and text to English before posting here, or remove them if they are not important.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your swapping algorithm:

```
    iTemp = iIndex1;
    iLotto[iTemp] = iLotto[iIndex1];
    iLotto[iIndex1] = iLotto[iIndex2];
    iLotto[iIndex2] = iLotto[iTemp];
```

It should be:

```
    iTemp           = iLotto[iIndex1];
    iLotto[iIndex1] = iLotto[iIndex2];
    iLotto[iIndex2] = iTemp;
```

---

Note that there's already a utility in C++ for doing this, namely `std::swap` from the `<utiliy>` header file:

```
std::swap(iLotto[iIndex1], iLotto[iIndex2]);
```

Also, don't use `srand()` and `rand()` if you are using C++11 (or later), use the functions from `<random>`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>    // begin, end
#include <random>      // mt19937 (modern random functions and classes)
#include <type_traits> // enable_if_t, is_integral_v, is_floating_point_v
#include <utility>     // swap

// A function to return a seeded random number generator.
inline std::mt19937& generator() {
    // the generator will only be seeded once (per thread) since it's static
    static thread_local std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    return gen;
}

// A function to generate integers in the range [min, max]
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
T my_rand(T min, T max) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist(min, max);
    return dist(generator());
}

// A function to generate floats in the range [min, max)
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr>
T my_rand(T min, T max) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(min, max);
    return dist(generator());
}

int main() {
    using std::cout;

    int iLotto[45] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 45; ++i) {
        iLotto[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::swap(iLotto[my_rand(0, 44)], iLotto[my_rand(0, 44)]);
    }
    // or better:
    // std::shuffle(std::begin(iLotto), std::end(iLotto), generator());

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        cout << iLotto[i] << "\t";
    }

    cout << "추가숫자:\t" << iLotto[7] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot read your code but I think you are approaching the problem wrong way around if you are not ask to do it this way. instead of shuffling a pre-generated range (which is costly)  you can generate 7 random numbers within desired range. if you want good quality random number generator which probably has low rate of repetition, you should look for 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get N unique but random numbers from a sequence of M unique and non-random (e.g. consecutive), a often used approach is to shuffle and array of the M numbers and then take the first N.

For shuffling using any established algorithm, e.g. [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 0):

try the srand() function.

Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/